# Converting sequential data from a .txt file to a data frame

Tags: python, dataframe, machine-learning, data-science, text-mining

Hello Data science community, I'm new at data science and python programming.
Here is the structure of my txt file but there are many missing values

```
#*Improved Channel Routing by Via Minimization and Shifting.
#@Chung-Kuan Cheng
David N. Deutsch
#t1988
#cDAC
#index131751
#%133716
#%133521
#%134343
#!Channel routing area improvement by means of via minimization and via shifting in two dimensions (compaction) is readily achievable. Routing feature area can be minimized by wire straightening. The implementation of algorithms for each of these procedures has produced a solution for Deutsch's Difficult Example
 the standard channel routing benchmark
 that is more than 5% smaller than the best result published heretofore. Suggestions for possible future work are also given.

#*A fast simultaneous input vector generation and gate replacement algorithm for leakage power reduction.
#@Lei Cheng
Liang Deng
Deming Chen
Martin D. F. Wong
#t2006
#cDAC
#index131752
#%132550
#%530568
#%436486
#%134259
#%283007
#%134422
#%282140
#%1134324
#!Input vector control (IVC) technique is based on the observation that the leakage current in a CMOS logic gate depends on the gate input state
 and a good input vector is able to minimize the leakage when the circuit is in the sleep mode. The gate replacement technique is a very effective method to further reduce the leakage current. In this paper
 we propose a fast algorithm to find a low leakage input vector with simultaneous gate replacement. Results on MCNC91 benchmark circuits show that our algorithm produces $14 %$ better leakage current reduction with several orders of magnitude speedup in runtime for large circuits compared to the previous state-of-the-art algorithm. In particular
 the average runtime for the ten largest combinational circuits has been dramatically reduced from 1879 seconds to 0.34 seconds.

#*On the Over-Specification Problem in Sequential ATPG Algorithms.
#@Kwang-Ting Cheng
Hi-Keung Tony Ma
#t1992
#cDAC
#index131756
#%455537
#%1078626
#%131745
#!The authors show that some ATPG (automatic test pattern generation) programs may err in identifying untestable faults. These test generators may not be able to find the test sequence for a testable fault
 even allowed infinite run time
 and may mistakenly claim it as untestable. The main problem of these programs is that the underlying combinational test generation algorithm may over-specify the requirements at the present state lines. A necessary condition that the underlying combinational test generation algorithm must satisfy is considered to ensure a correct sequential ATPG program. It is shown that the simple D-algorithm satisfies this condition while PODEM and the enhanced D-algorithm do not. The impact of over-specification on the length of the generated test sequence was studied. Over-specification caused a longer test sequence. Experimental results are presented

#*Device and architecture co-optimization for FPGA power reduction.
#@Lerong Cheng
Phoebe Wong
Fei Li
Yan Lin
Lei He
#t2005
#cDAC
#index131759
#%214244
#%215701
#%214503
#%282575
#%214411
#%214505
#%132929
#!Device optimization considering supply voltage Vdd and threshold voltage Vt tuning does not increase chip area but has a great impact on power and performance in the nanometer technology. This paper studies the simultaneous evaluation of device and architecture optimization for FPGA. We first develop an efficient yet accurate timing and power evaluation method
 called trace-based model. By collecting trace information from cycle-accurate simulation of placed and routed FPGA benchmark circuits and re-using the trace for different Vdd and Vt
 we enable the device and architecture co-optimization for hundreds of combinations. Compared to the baseline FPGA which has the architecture same as the commercial FPGA used by Xilinx
 and has Vdd suggested by ITRS but Vt optimized by our device optimization
 architecture and device co-optimization can reduce energy-delay product by 20.5% without any chip area increase compared to the conventional FPGA architecture. Furthermore
 considering power-gating of unused logic blocks and interconnect switches
 our co-optimization method reduces energy-delay product by 54.7% and chip area by 8.3%. To the best of our knowledge
 this is the first in-depth study on architecture and device co-optimization for FPGAs.
```

I want to convert it to a data frame , exp lines which start by #@ are authors , #! are abstracts ,#* are titles ,#% are references and #c are venues using python
Each article start by its title , the problem may have to do with abstracts

I tried different approaches such as

```
import csv
with open('names7.csv', 'w', encoding="utf-8") as csvfile:
    fieldnames = ["Venue", "Year", "Authors","Title","id","ListCitation","NbrCitations","Abstract"]
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()
    with open(r"C:\Users\lenovo\Downloads\1.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
        cnt = 1
        for line in f :           
            if line.startswith('#*'):
                writer.writerow({'Title': line})
                cnt += 1
            elif line.startswith('#@'):
                writer.writerow({'Authors': line})
                cnt += 1
            elif line.startswith("#t"):
                writer.writerow({'Year': line})
                cnt += 1
            elif line.startswith("#!"):
                writer.writerow({'Abstract': line})
                cnt += 1
            elif line.startswith("#c"):
                writer.writerow({'Venue': line})
                cnt +=1
            elif line.startswith("#index"):
                writer.writerow({'id': line}) 
                cnt +=1
            else:
                writer.writerow({'ListCitation': line}) 
                cnt +=1
    f.close()
```

I tried this aproache but it didn't work i want to convert it to data frame with the said columns, how can i convert this file to a data frame and storing result in csv file

the output of answer's code [image: 1]

There the output that i want
[image]

for example for this case (abstract column) there is space between paragraphs which caused me a problem so this case must be taken into account and for the column reference there are many references so , they mus be taken into account

```
#*Total power reduction in CMOS circuits via gate sizing and multiple threshold voltages.
#@Feng Gao
John P. Hayes
#t2005
#cDAC
#index132139
#%437038
#%437006
#%436596
#%285977
#%1135402
#%132206
#%194016
#%143061
#!Minimizing power consumption is one of the most important objectives in IC design. Resizing gates and assigning different Vt's are common ways to meet power and timing budgets. We propose an automatic implementation of both these techniques using a mixedinteger linear programming model called MLP-exact
 which minimizes a circuit's total active-mode power consumption. Unlike previous linear programming methods which only consider local optimality
 MLP-exact
 can find a true global optimum. An efficient
 non-optimal way to solve the MLP model
 called MLP-fast

 is also described. We present a set of benchmark experiments which show that MLP-fast
 is much faster than MLP-exact

 while obtaining designs with only slightly higher power consumption. Furthermore
 the designs generated by MLP-fast
 consume 30% less power than those obtained by conventional
 sensitivity-based methods.
```

Answer (score 0):

`csv.DictWriter().writerow()` takes a dictionary representing the entire row for that specific sample. What's happening to your code right now is, everything you call writerow, its creating a completely new row instead of adding to the current row. Instead, what you should do is

1. define a variable called row as a dictionary
2. store the values for the entire row in this variable
3. write to the csv using writerow for this dictionary

This will write the entire row to the csv instead of a new row for every new value.

Though this is not the only problem we must look at. Each new line in the text document that does not have a starting id is considered a value it is not. For example !Channel is separated across 3 lines of text, yet only the first line will be considered as `!Channel` while the other 2 lines will be considered as something else.

Below is a improved version of code with documentation using a dictionary to store starting values and corresponding ids. To add new cases, just modify the dictionary `keys` and `fieldnames`

```
"""
#@ are authors
#! are abstracts
#* are titles
#% are references
#index are index
#c are venues using python Each article start by its title , the problem may have to do with abstracts
"""

# use dictionary to store fieldnames with corresponding id's/tags
keys = {
        'Venue': '#c',
        'Year':'#t',
        'Authors':'#@',
        'Title':'#*',
        'id': '#index',
        'References': '#%',
        'Abstract': '#!',
}

fieldnames = ["Venue", "Year", "Authors", "Title","id","Abstract", 'References']

outFile = 'names7.csv' # path to csv output
inFile = r"1.txt" # path to input text file

import csv
with open(outFile, 'w', encoding="utf-8") as csvfile:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()
    with open(inFile, "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
        row = dict()
        stack = [] # (key, value) pair, used to store multiple values regarding rows
        for line in f:
            line = line.strip() # remove white space from beginning and end of line
            prev = "" # store value of previous column
            for col in fieldnames: 
                # if column is defined and doesnt start with any id, add to previous value
                # this handles cases with results over one line or containing new lines
                if prev in row and not any([line.startswith(prefix) for prefix in keys.items()]):
                    # remove prefix
                    prefix = keys[prev]
                    line = line[len(prefix):]

                    row[prev] += ' ' + line
                # initate or append to current value. Handles (References #%)
                elif col in keys and line.startswith(keys[col]):
                    # remove prefix
                    prefix = keys[col]
                    line = line[len(prefix):]
                    if col in row:
                        stack.append((col, line))
                    else:
                        row[col] = line
                    prev = col # define prev col if answer goes over one line
                    break # go to next line in text
        writer.writerow(row)
        for col, line in stack:
            row[col] = line
            writer.writerow(row)
        f.close()
```

Result produced given test case above.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer but when i tried your code it didn't store each value in the said column rapeat each value in all the columns

Comment: What you tell me what your output looks like? If we have multiple values for a column, do you want a new row for each?

Comment: yeah iwant to insert each value in the corresponding column please check the edited question to see the output of your code

Comment: I updated the code, try it out now. Attached is an image of my result based on the given test case. Let me know if you'd like help in anything else

Comment: Anthony it worked but it repeats the rows. and there is the space between the rows

Comment: and for exp when there are a missing value the field must stay empty

Comment: is there anything new.

Answer (score 0):

Updated Previous Answer with this result produced given this specific text file

[image]

```
"""
#@ are authors
#! are abstracts
#* are titles
#% are references
#index are index
#c are venues using python Each article start by its title , the problem may have to do with abstracts
"""

# use dictionary to store fieldnames with corresponding id's/tags
keys = {
    '#c': 'Venue',
    '#t': 'Year',
    '#@': 'Authors',
    '#*': 'Title',
    '#index': 'id',
    '#%': 'References',
    '#!': 'Abstract'
}


fieldnames = ["Venue", "Year", "Authors", "Title", "NbrAuthor", "id", "ListCitation", "NbrCitation", "References", "NbrReferences", "Abstract"]

# fieldnames = ["Venue", "Year", "Authors", "Title", "NbrAuthor", "id", "ListCitation", "NbrCitation"]



# References and Authors store on one line
# Count number of authors and references
# We want to count the Authors, NbrAuthor, NbrCitations

outFile = 'names7.csv' # path to csv output
inFile = r"1.txt" # path to input text file

import csv
import re
with open(outFile, 'w', encoding="utf-8") as csvfile:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()
    with open(inFile, "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
        row = dict()
        prev = ""
        for line in f.readlines():
            line = line.strip() # remove any leading or trailing whitespace
            # remove any parentheses at the end of the string
            query = re.findall(r'\([^)]*\)', line)
            if len(query) > 0:
                line = line.replace(query[-1], '')
            # if none of the keys match, then belongs to previous key
            if prev != "" and not any([line.startswith(k) for k in keys]):
                if prev == 'Abstract':
                    row[prev] += " " + line
                else:
                    row[prev] += ", " + line
            else:
                for k in keys:
                    prefix = ""
                    if line.startswith(k):
                        # remove prefix
                        prefix = k
                        line = line[len(prefix):]
                        if keys[k] in row:
                            if keys[k] == "References":
                                row[keys[k]] += ", " + line
                            else:
                                row[keys[k]] += " " + line
                        else:
                            row[keys[k]] = line
                        prev = keys[k]
        # count number of references and Citations
        row["NbrAuthor"] = row["Authors"].count(',') + 1
        row["NbrCitation"] = 0
        row["NbrReferences"] = row["References"].count(',') + 1
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: Hello Anthony it returns the same ouput as the update of my question

Comment: Hi Zakb, this algorithm works for the given text file above. It looks like you want an algorithm that works for a different input. I'd recommend updating the question to reflect this. - Anthony

Comment: Hi Anthony thank you for your answer i want it for this input data  but the output of your new algo is the same as the first one it didn't insert each row in the said column please see the output in the updated question

Comment: please  i want it to store each value in the said column especially the authors(there are more than one author) and abstracts and references

Comment: Please see the updated question so you will see more of the structure of my txt file so you will learn more of the structure of my data

Comment: Hi Zakb, I updated the program based on the file you uploaded. It should work now

Answer (score 0):

Edit: added clause to if statement

```
prefixes = {
    '#*': 'Title',
    '#@': 'Authors',
    '#t': 'Year',
    '#c': 'Venue',
    '#index': 'id',
    '#%': 'References',
    '#!': 'Abstract',
}


outFile = 'names7.csv' # path to csv output
inFile = r"1.txt" # path to input text file

import csv
import re
with open(outFile, 'w', encoding="utf-8") as csvfile:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=list(prefixes.values()) + ['NbrAuthor', 'NbrCitations', 'ListCitations'])
    writer.writeheader()
    with open(inFile, "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
        row = dict()
        prev = ''
        for line in f.readlines():
            # remove leading and trailing whitespace
            line = line.strip()

            # remove close brackets at end of lines
            # query = re.findall(r'\([^)]*\)', line)
            # if len(query) > 0:
            #     line = line.replace(query[-1], '')

            for prefix, col in prefixes.items():
                if line.startswith(prefix):
                    line = line[len(prefix):]
                    if col == "Authors" or col == 'Abstract':
                        row[col] = ""
                    else:
                        row[col] = line
                    prev = prefix
                    break
            
            # special cases
            try:
                if prev == '#@':
                    if row['Authors'] == "":
                        row['Authors'] = line
                    else:
                        row['Authors'] += ', ' + line
                elif prev == '#%':
                    row['References'] += ', ' + line
                elif prev == '#!':
                    row['Abstract'] += ' ' + line
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
                
            if len(line) == 0:
                row['NbrAuthor'] = row['Authors'].count(',') + 1
                row['NbrCitations'] = 0
                writer.writerow(row)
                prev = ''
                row = dict()
```

Comment: Hi Anthony it gives me value Keyerror:Authors ``` row['NbrAuthor'] = row['Authors'].count(',') + 1```

Comment: and it repeat the same reference and the same abstract without considering the next line

Comment: Do some rows of the text file not have an author?

Comment: Do all the rows have the same sequence, ie. Title, Author, year, etc ? And also, do the rows have missing values?

Comment: I updated the answer to have a try except clause that catches the Keyerror:Authors. This only happens if the row has no author.

Comment: no  there are missing values thanks anthony your code work perfecty but for the reference and abstract it repeat the same line for exemple for title improved channel it repeat the first line of its abstrat tree times:(Channel routing area improvement by means of via minimization and via shifting in two dimensions (compaction) is readily achievable. Routing feature area can be minimized by wire straightening. The implementation of algorithms for each of these procedures has produced a solution for Deutsch's Difficult Example)

Comment: thanks it worked for abstract but it repeat the same number of reference for exemple for title improved channel it repeat the last line of reference two times:134343